# Download npm package and install from local directory

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, npm-install

I want to install a package 'angular-tree-component' from my local directory instead of directly installing it as per its documentation.

For that I cloned the package from Git in my local_module folder and added '"angular-tree-component": "file:local_modules/angular-tree-component"' to my package dependencies.

When I am directly using 'npm i angular-tree-component' in my project, i can see a angular-tree-component folder added to my node_module which has a dist folder.

But when i am installing it from my local directly, its just linking my 'angular-tree-component' folder from local_modules to node_modules and dist folder is not created.

Kindly suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: Why not just use npm install?

Comment: I want to keep it locally and try some stuff.